# Hibernate dialect for Redshift

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

There are multiple databases used in my application and redshift is one of them. Because of using hibernate framework for configuring the connections I am trying to use appropriate dialect for redshift. But both **PostgreSQL9Dialect** and **MySQL5InnoDBDialect** are working for me.

Curious to know which dialect is best for Redshift? 
Also, I have below questions.

Is dialect mandatory while using hibernate?

What is the default dialect if nothing is mentioned?

Comment: Given Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8, it should be clear that you shouldn't be using a MySQL based dialect. That probably only works by accident until you hit something that isn't valid PostgreSQL/Redshift syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Redshift` is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2 (see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)) , it is better to use PostgreSQL dialect. Since it has some differences between PostgreSQL, it is not surprise that it will not work for some cases but you could have a try.

Dialect is mandatory for hibernate . If you do not specify a dialect , it will try to choose the most suitable one for you based on the metadata get from the JDBC driver. If no dialect can be chosen , it will throw an exception saying that [`Unable to determine Dialect to use`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/8f344af218305ca71cab9e1304627f4541236894/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/dialect/internal/DialectFactoryImpl.java#L106).